# django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL: database does not exist (postgres / deploy to digitalocean)

Tags: django, postgresql, digital-ocean, django-database, django-deployment

I am trying to deploy a project with digital ocean. I followed the instructions found at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04 
Some of the important ones:
I ran:

```
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE jobzumoDB;
CREATE DATABASE
```

then:

```
postgres=# CREATE USER admin WITH PASSWORD '123';
CREATE ROLE
postgres=# GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE jobzumoDB  TO admin;
GRANT
```

set the following in settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'jobzumoDB',
        'USER':'admin',
        'PASSWORD':'123',
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT':'',
    }
```

then tried to run:

```
 ~/jobzumo/manage.py makemigrations
```

and got:

```
 File "/home/justin/jobzumo/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
        conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
    django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "jobzumoDB" does not exist
```

Two things:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['jobzumo.com', '142.93.184.125']
```

I have not yet connect jobzumo.com to digital ocean, but the IP address was copied from my droplet.

Also, I ran: `pip install django gunicorn psycopg2` (from digitial ocean)

but a tutorial on youtube said it was very important to now
install `psycopg2-binary` instead, however, I did not do this as the video was veering far from digital ocean's tutorial.

Thanks for any help, after starting to understand django I didn't think deploying would be this much of a headscratcher.

Comment: your database name is incorrect. check it

Comment: one useful debugging step here would be to try to connect to the database manually via cli - you should be able to do it like so: `sudo -u postgres psql -d jobzumoDB -U admin -W 123`

Comment: @nthall returns `psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "admin"`

Comment: @nthall I started with a youtube tutorial where I created a user 'justin' and this 'admin' user for some reason so I feel I might have screwed up and should start from the beginning only trying to follow digital oceans resources

Comment: sorry - add `-h localhost` and try again

Comment: @nthall that actually got me `psql: FATAL:  database "jobzumoDB" does not exist`

Comment: I thought `postgres=# CREATE DATABASE jobzumoDB;`
 returning `CREATE DATABASE` was confirmation that it worked lol

Comment: next thing to try imo would be `sudo -u postgres psql -c '\l'` to list all databases.

Comment: @nthall there it is listed as 'jobzumodb' not 'jobzumoDB'! After changing that in settings.py `makemigrations` worked without a problem. Thank you, you've been tremendously helpful. If I wanted to learn more do I just need to read into postgres db? These are all commands I am unfamiliar with.

Comment: @user3131132 i did a little research into *why* this happened, would appreciate it if you could vote & accept my answer :D

Comment: @nthall sorry had to go to work after I didn't respond yesterday

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Formalizing what we worked out in the comments as an answer, when you give postgres an unquoted string as an identifier, it forces it to lower-case. [see this similar answer from pgsql-general mailing list](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4989FA67.4010706%40archonet.com). So the actual name of the database created by the command `CREATE DATABASE jobzumoDB;` is `jobzumodb`. to create a database named `jobzumoDB` it's necessary to use quotes, as in `CREATE DATABASE "jobzumoDB";`

Comment: amazing! Spent a lot of time before I found this. Thanks @nthall

Answer (score 0):

### Use:

### NAME': 'jobzumodb',

### Instead of:

### NAME': 'jobzumoDB',

Comment: Please write your answer in lowercase. and this answer has been already given by nthall